# jQuery combobox/autocomplete but editable

Tags: jquery, combobox

I'm using the jQuery [Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox) but I need it to be editable.  What I mean is that if a value isn't in the list, I need to capture the value they entered.  Using the example in the above link, the user may not see their choice, C# for example, and would type their language.  What I found in the default behavior is that if the value isn't found in the list, it clears the user response.

I added the following code:

```
options: {
  allowUserDefined: false
},
```

and

```
var self = this,
    **options = this.options,**
```

and

```
if (!valid && !options.allowUserDefined) {
  // remove invalid value, as it didn't match anything
  $(this).val("");
  select.val("");
  input.data("autocomplete").term = "";
  return false;
}
```

to prevent the response from being cleared.  And these few changes does work.  But since C# isn't found in the list, there isn't a selected option to return.

How can I have the code return what is entered in the input field?  While debugging the code, specifically in the `change` event, input.val() contains the text entered and that's what I need.  I just can't figure out how to get access to this value.

Thank you.

Here is my complete js file:

```
(function ($) {
    $.widget("ui.combobox", {
        options: {
            allowUserDefined: false
        },
        _create: function () {
            if (this.options.allowUserDefined === null) {
                this.options.allowUserDefined = false;
            }

            var self = this,
                    options = this.options,
                    select = this.element.hide(),
                    selected = select.children(":selected"),
                    value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";
            var input = this.input = $("<input>")
                    .insertAfter(select)
                    .val(value)
                    .autocomplete({
                        delay: 0,
                        minLength: 0,
                        source: function (request, response) {
                            var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
                            response(select.children("option").map(function () {
                                var text = $(this).text();
                                if (this.value && (!request.term || matcher.test(text)))
                                    return {
                                        label: text.replace(
                                            new RegExp(
                                                "(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" +
                                                $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term) +
                                                ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "gi"
                                            ), "<strong>$1</strong>"),
                                        value: text,
                                        option: this
                                    };
                            }));
                        },
                        select: function (event, ui) {
                            ui.item.option.selected = true;
                            self._trigger("selected", event, {
                                item: ui.item.option
                            });
                        },
                        change: function (event, ui) {
                            if (!ui.item) {
                                var matcher = new RegExp("^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex($(this).val()) + "$", "i"),
                                    valid = false;
                                select.children("option").each(function () {
                                    if ($(this).text().match(matcher)) {
                                        this.selected = valid = true;
                                        return false;
                                    }
                                });
                                if (!valid && !options.allowUserDefined) {
                                    // remove invalid value, as it didn't match anything
                                    $(this).val("");
                                    select.val("");
                                    input.data("autocomplete").term = "";
                                    return false;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    .addClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-left");

            input.data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
                return $("<li></li>")
                        .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                        .append("<a>" + item.label + "</a>")
                        .appendTo(ul);
            };

            this.button = $("<button type='button'>&nbsp;</button>")
                    .attr("tabIndex", -1)
                    .attr("title", "Show All Items")
                    .insertAfter(input)
                    .button({
                        icons: {
                            primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
                        },
                        text: false
                    })
                    .removeClass("ui-corner-all")
                    .addClass("ui-corner-right ui-button-icon")
                    .click(function () {
                        // close if already visible
                        if (input.autocomplete("widget").is(":visible")) {
                            input.autocomplete("close");
                            return;
                        }

                        // work around a bug (likely same cause as #5265)
                        $(this).blur();

                        // pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
                        input.autocomplete("search", "");
                        input.focus();
                    });
        },

        destroy: function () {
            this.input.remove();
            this.button.remove();
            this.element.show();
            $.Widget.prototype.destroy.call(this);
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

**Update**

Using Darkajax's code (I like the strict option better than what I came up with), I can get the value of the input box by doing this:

```
var valu = $("#combobox").parent().children()[1].value;
```

Comment: Good, I'm glad I was able to contribute at least a little!

Answer (score 5):

What I do myself when using the jQuery UI autocomplete combobox is to declare the combobox widget like this:

```
(function( $ ) {
    $.widget( "ui.combobox", {
        // default options
        options: {
            strict: false
        },
        _create: function() {
            var self = this,
                select = this.element.hide(),
                selected = select.children( ":selected" ),
                value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "",
                strict = this.options.strict;

            var input = this.input = $( "<input>" )
                .insertAfter( select )
                .val( value )
                .autocomplete({
                    delay: 0,
                    minLength: 0,
                    source: function( request, response ) {
                        var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i" );
                        response( select.children( "option" ).map(function() {
                            var text = $( this ).text();
                            if ( this.value && ( !request.term || matcher.test(text) ) )
                                return {
                                    label: text.replace(
                                        new RegExp(
                                            "(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" +
                                            $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term) +
                                            ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "gi"
                                        ), "<strong>$1</strong>" ),
                                    value: text,
                                    option: this
                                };
                        }) );
                    },
                    select: function( event, ui ) {
                        ui.item.option.selected = true;
                        self._trigger( "selected", event, {
                            item: ui.item.option
                        });
                    },
                    autocomplete : function(value) {
                        this.element.val(value);
                        this.input.val(value);
                    },
                    change: function( event, ui ) {
                        if ( !ui.item ) {
                            var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( $(this).val() ) + "$", "i" ),
                                valid = false;
                            select.children( "option" ).each(function() {
                                if ( this.value.match( matcher ) ) {
                                    this.selected = valid = true;
                                    return false;
                                }
                            });
                            if ( !valid ) {
                                // if strict is true, then unmatched values are not allowed
                                if ( strict ) {
                                    // remove invalid value, as it didn't match anything
                                    $( this ).val( "" );
                                    select.val( "" );
                                }
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
                .addClass( "ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-left" );

            input.data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
                return $( "<li></li>" )
                    .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
                    .append( "<a>" + item.label + "</a>" )
                    .appendTo( ul );
            };

            this.button = $( "<button type=\"button\" class=combo_button>&nbsp;</button>" )
                .attr( "tabIndex", -1 )
                .attr( "title", "Show All Items" )
                .insertAfter( input )
                .button({
                    icons: {
                        primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
                    },
                    text: false
                })
                .removeClass( "ui-corner-all" )
                .addClass( "ui-corner-right ui-button-icon" )
                .click(function() {
                    // close if already visible
                    if ( input.autocomplete( "widget" ).is( ":visible" ) ) {
                        input.autocomplete( "close" );
                        return;
                    }

                    // pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
                    input.autocomplete( "search", "" );
                    input.focus();
                });
        }
    });
})( jQuery );
```

That would make it accept other options as valid values, and you'll just have to use:

```
$("#combobox").combobox({
    strict: true
});
```

To make it work as default just in case you need it.

Comment: Thanks for the response darkajax.  I'm still not able to get the value typed in; it seems to just return the first item in the list.  I know there has got to be a way :)

Answer (score 0):

In your

```
source: function(request, response)
{
```

you can access the `request.term` = what was typed.

Answer (score 0):

Using the cleaner solution from darkajax, and the following line of code:

```
var valu = $("#combobox").parent().children()[1].value;
```

I was able to get the value of the combobox.

Answer (score 0):

I have no clue if this will help anyone, but by giving the input a name, the value was submitted.... (I removed the code that removed invalid entries, of course)

```
var input = this.input = $("<input name='somehthing'>")
```