# jquery change event not firing?

Tags: jquery, events, combobox

I'm trying to update a hidden input item based on a change event in a combobox. I have a bunch of dropdowns, that I will dynamically change to a combobox, if they are of a certain class ("test1"). I wanted to add that I am using some jquery I found here to get an "open" combobox....i.e. one that will accept any user input and not just what is available in the options list. I used the javascript provided here for this purpose: [jQuery combobox/autocomplete but editable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9473268/jquery-combobox-autocomplete-but-editable)

However, only one of the following works...

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".test1").combobox();
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".test1").change(function () {
            alert('test'); //Other logic to update hidden elements.

        }
        );
    });
```

If I comment out the function, that turns the dropdown into a combobox, then the alert fires. If I turn off the alert function, the combobox call works and the dropdown changes to a combobox. Can anyone please suggest a solution?

**Update:**

I figured out why this was not working (at least I think so). In the link above, the change behaviour for the combobox is already handled. My extra change event handler does not get registered. I had to add my code into the change event itself (like this snippet):

```
    change: function (event, ui) {
                var selset = "CHF Discharge Diagnosis";
                    $(':hidden').filter($('input[selsetname="' + selset + '"]')).val(this.value);
                    alert($(':hidden').filter($('input[selsetname="' + selset + '"]')).val());

                    if (!ui.item) {
                        var matcher = new RegExp("^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex($(this).val()) + "$", "i"),
                            valid = false;
```

Comment: Maybe try putting `$('.test1').combobox();` inside of the change function?

Comment: You need to give more details, but if you change an input value with javascript, the onchange event won't fire.

Comment: You only need one document ready function. All your functions go inside of it.

Comment: Do they really need to be in different $(document).ready functions? Try putting them in the same one. Then you could chain them:  `$('.test1').change(function(){...}).combobox();`. Also, could you specify which combobox plugin you are using? I found a few with the same name and I want to make sure we know what you're using.

Comment: I've added some extra information to my question about how I am using the combobox. Also, lbstr, I did try to put them in one javascript function. that did not work.

Comment: @Sai OK, then I am inclined to agree with the answers below that suggest the combobox plugin is altering the html. It sounds like combobox offers a onChange hook, so you should use that. If Zefiryn's answer isn't completely correct, its probably extremely close, so play around until you get something.

Answer (score 0):

If combobox is changing the html structure (for example creates ul or div elements instead of form selects and inputs) then it may not trigger change event on that elements. But here: http://jquery.sanchezsalvador.com/jquery/page/jquerycomboboxapi.aspx at the bottom is a snippet with `onChange` method. Based on that try the following

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var cb = $(".test1").combobox();
    cb.combobox.onChange = function() {
        alert('test'); //Other logic to update hidden elements.
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out why this was not working (at least I think so). In the link where the UI widget is defined (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9473268/jquery-combobox-autocomplete-but-editable), the change behaviour for the combobox is already handled. My extra change event handler does not get registered. I had to add my code into the change event itself (like this snippet):

```
change: function (event, ui) {
            var selset = "CHF Discharge Diagnosis";
                $(':hidden').filter($('input[selsetname="' + selset + '"]')).val(this.value);
                alert($(':hidden').filter($('input[selsetname="' + selset + '"]')).val());

                if (!ui.item) {
                    var matcher = new RegExp("^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex($(this).val()) + "$", "i"),
                        valid = false;
```